# How does the style of Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl" affect the way it's read?

Tags: short-stories, style, jamaica-kincaid

Jamaica Kincaid's "Girl" is written in a very distinct style. The story is made up of one very long sentence, with different phrases separated by semicolons, each phrase giving a different piece of advice.

> Wash the white clothes on Monday and put them on the stone heap; wash the color clothes on Tuesday and put them on the clothesline to dry; don’t walk bare-head in the hot sun; cook pumpkin fritters in very hot sweet oil; soak your little cloths right after you take them off; [...]

How does the style affect the way the story is read, as opposed to, say, if was made up of phrases separated by periods?

> Wash the white clothes on Monday and put them on the stone heap. Wash the color clothes on Tuesday and put them on the clothesline to dry. Don’t walk bare-head in the hot sun. Cook pumpkin fritters in very hot sweet oil. Soak your little cloths right after you take them off. [...]

How do the semicolons affect the tone of the work, and how it's interpreted? Why specifically this distinct style for "giving advice"?